# Qual è il tempo verbale giusto in questa frase?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood

Oggi ho detto questa frase:

*Bastava che trovasse qualcuno che glielo prestasse*

ma sono stato ripreso. È sbagliata? Perché?

Answer (score 5):

Devi usare il condizionale: "Sarebbe bastato che" oppure "basterebbe" a seconda del significato che vuoi dare, che nel tuo caso non è chiarissimo. È la formula tipica di una frase condizionale.

Si usa spesso il tempo imperfetto, ma non è corretto. La forma della frase è

Condizionale + che + congiuntivo.

Quindi hai i due casi:

> "Sarebbe bastato trovare qualcuno che glielo avesse prestato"

Oppure

> "Basterebbe che trovasse qualcuno che glielo prestasse"

Nel primo caso, ormai è tardi: non troverà nessuno. Nel secondo caso c'è ancora della speranza, e può essere resa senza il primo "che":

> "Basterebbe trovasse qualcuno che glielo prestasse"

Edit-----------------------------------------------

Forse dobbiamo passare a un caso reale per capirci meglio. 
Esempio: il nostro amico aveva un appuntamento a cui non è andato perché nessuno gli ha prestato la bici.

**Caso 1**: L'appuntamento è oggi pomeriggio e il nostro amico è in giro in cerca di uno che gli presti la bici.

> "Basterebbe trovasse qualcuno che glielo prestasse"

**Caso 2**: L'appuntamento era ieri pomeriggio e il nostro amico prima di ieri pomeriggio ha cercato di farsi prestare la bici.

> "Sarebbe bastato trovare qualcuno che glielo avesse prestato"

**Caso 3**: L'appuntamento è nell'immediato futuro, ma ormai è tardi ed è impossibile trovare una bici.

> "Sarebbe bastato trovare qualcuno che glielo avesse prestato"

**Caso 4**: L'appuntamento è oggi pomeriggio e il nostro amico avrebbe bisogno di farsi prestare una bici proprio ora.

> "Sarebbe bastato trovare qualcuno che gliela prestasse"

**Caso 1**: l'appuntamento è nell'immediato futuro e ho ancora possibilità di farcela (quindi uso il presente in entrambi i verbi).

**Caso 2-3**: l'appuntamento è passato o è troppo vicino e non ho possibilità di farcela (quindi uso il passato in entrambi i verbi).

**Caso 4**: l'appuntamento è nell'immediato futuro ed il mio amico è andato ieri a cercare una bici, senza successo. L'atto del farsi prestare la bici avverrebbe ora (quindi posso usare il presente), ma ormai sta diventando troppo tardi.

Comment: Vuoi dire che "Sarebbe bastato trovare qualcuno che glielo prestasse" è sbagliato?

Comment: @WalterTross Dipende cosa vuoi dire. La tua frase significa che "Sarebbe bastato" trovare qualcuno in passato. Però quando sarebbe avvenuta l'azione del prestare? Se io ieri cercavo una persona per farmi prestare nel presente, uso il presente. Se io ieri cercavo una persona per farmi prestare prima del momento di cui parlo, allora uso il passato. 
Quindi devi dividere i tempi: quando avviene l'azione del prestare?

Comment: L'azione del prestare, nel momento a cui si riferisce la frase, è ipotetica, quindi non ha senso chiedersi quando avviene.

Comment: @WalterTross Certo che ha senso chiedersi quando avviene, altrimenti non sappiamo che tempo verbale usare. Io chiedo in prestito una cosa per quale momento? Edito la domanda per renderla più chiara con un esempio concreto.

Comment: Ti consiglio, invece di editare la domanda, di editare la risposta prendendo posizione su "Sarebbe bastato trovare qualcuno che glielo prestasse"

Comment: @WalterTross spero così sia più chiaro!

Comment: Secondo la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperfetto_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/),  sezione 3.3, più che di "forma sbagliata" o di "forma non corretta", si dovrebbe parlare di "forma substandard".

Comment: "L’imperfetto indicativo in periodo ipotetico si trova sin dall’antichità anche in costruzioni miste (proprie sia dello scritto che dell’orale; Mazzoleni 1992: 175-179), in cui le normali forme del congiuntivo imperfetto o del condizionale, rispettivamente nella protasi e nell’apodosi, sono sostituite dall’imperfetto indicativo."

Comment: "*che s’io fossi giù stato, io ti mostrava // di mio amor più altre che le fronde*" (Dante, Par. VIII, 56-57)

Comment: @Nicol: a me sembra che Dante in questa frase abbia fatto il tuo stesso "errore".

Comment: Sì... ma Dante può*te*